# viewDidAppear: doesn't get the chance to execute if two local notifications expire at the exact same time - anyway to make it?

Tags: ios

My app listens for local notifications and when they fire it pushes a view controller onto the navigation stack.

However if two notifications fire at the exact same time then I have noticed that the viewDidAppear: from the push of the first view controller does not get a chance to execute before the delegate's didReceiveLocalNotification: gets called with the 2nd notification.

This results in a ""Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for..." message in the console and the views not displaying properly.

Is there a way I can make the ViewDidAppear: from the push of the first controller execute before didReceiveLocalNotification: gets invoked for the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Delay your processing of the second notification until `-viewDidAppear:` fires.

Comment: I have tried that but without success. Using something like: double delayInSeconds = 0.3;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [[self.navigationController topViewController].navigationController     pushViewController:detailController animated:YES]; 
});

Comment: That's not what I meant by delay. I meant that if you're already in the middle of a transition, stick your notification (or some object that represents it) into a queue for later processing, and then process the next object in that queue in response to `-viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: I found out something interesting: if the push is done with animation the warning message appears, if down without animation it doesn't. However I'll be adding a queue.